# What is opt_initialTime relative to?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am calling `player.load(protocol, 17800)` for live audio stream (duration Infinity).  I want to start **17800** seconds after the timestamp of the first segment based on `(#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME)`.

The player is not starting in `17800` seconds.  I am off by about 7 minutes.  The playlist manifest is 5 hours long.  I want to start close to live but not necessarily at the live point.  Is there a way to do this?

I do not know what `opt_initialTime` is relative to?  I assume the first segment of the playlist that is pulled.  Can someone from Google explain how the google cast media player handles that second parameter of load?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Player#load), `opt_initialTime` is the time from which to start the playback in seconds. This parameter is used in [`load`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Player#load) and [`preload`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Player#preload) methods.

From this [link](https://plus.google.com/104024344976761899321/posts/1nTKrAEfCPq), it discussed how are the `load(opt_protocol, opt_initialTime)` and `preload(opt_protocol, opt_initialTime)` supposed to work in the Media Player Library.

> Our testing shows that load with an initial time specified works. Preload with an initial time works by downloading segments as specified by the initial time. If that is then followed by a load then that takes precedent and will start the playback from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @abielita. FYI, it turned out that durations listed as 10, were 9.75 in actuality.  This accounted for the discrepancy.